# parse html for specific words python

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, urllib2

I'm trying to call a website and search the website's for specific words.

Right now I have:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.mtb.com")
page_source = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
```

I would like to search the html for the word "Chat" (in reality it's a long list of different words).

If I do something like

```
"Chat" in soup
False

"Chat" in page_source
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Looking at the website's source code, I can see that it does have `Chat`. I want to see if the word exists in the html (they are using a chat tool), not *only* if the word exists as *text on the webpage*. (its fine if it exists on the webpage as well)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using BeautifulSoup as well, simply with regular expressions. As the scraped page is returned in the format of a byte like object so  `x = page_source.decode()`  will convert byte like object to string

Full code:

```
import urllib.request

from urllib.request import urlopen

import re

response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.mtb.com")

page_source = response.read()

x = page_source.decode()

y = re.findall(r'[C][h][a][t]', x)

print(y)
```